# How to save entitie to database from my controller' Action with symfony 3.3

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to creat a row in  Advert table from entity advert located in  my controller **AdvertController.php**  exactly in  **addAction ()**. :

**\Symfony\src\OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert.php** :

```
<?php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Advert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OC\PlatformBundle\Repository\AdvertRepository")
 */
class Advert
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="published", type="boolean")
     */
    private $published = true;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Par défaut, la date de l'annonce est la date d'aujourd'hui
        $this->date = new \Datetime();
    }


    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date.
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set title.
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set author.
     *
     * @param string $author
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set content.
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }




    /**
     * Set published.
     *
     * @param bool $published
     *
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function setPublished($published)
    {
        $this->published = $published;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get published.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getPublished()
    {
        return $this->published;
    }
}
```

**Symfony\src\OC\PlatformBundle\Controller\AdvertController.php** :

```
<?php

// src/OC/PlatformBundle/Controller/AdvertController.php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Controller;

// N'oubliez pas ce use :
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class AdvertController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        // Notre liste d'annonce en dur
        $listAdverts = array(
            array(
                'title'   => 'Recherche développpeur Symfony',
                'id'      => 1,
                'author'  => 'Alexandre',
                'content' => 'Nous recherchons un développeur Symfony débutant sur Lyon. Blabla…',
                'date'    => new \Datetime()),
            array(
                'title'   => 'Mission de webmaster',
                'id'      => 2,
                'author'  => 'Hugo',
                'content' => 'Nous recherchons un webmaster capable de maintenir notre site internet. Blabla…',
                'date'    => new \Datetime()),
            array(
                'title'   => 'Offre de stage webdesigner',
                'id'      => 3,
                'author'  => 'Mathieu',
                'content' => 'Nous proposons un poste pour webdesigner. Blabla…',
                'date'    => new \Datetime())
        );
        // Et modifiez le 2nd argument pour injecter notre liste
        return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:index.html.twig', array(
            'listAdverts' => $listAdverts
        ));
    }

    public function menuAction($limit){
        // On fixe en dur une liste ici, bien entendu par la suite
        // on la récupérera depuis la BDD !
        $listAdverts = array(
            array('id' => 2, 'title' => 'Recherche développeur Symfony'),
            array('id' => 5, 'title' => 'Mission de webmaster'),
            array('id' => 9, 'title' => 'Offre de stage webdesigner')
        );

        return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:menu.html.twig', array(
            // Tout l'intérêt est ici : le contrôleur passe
            // les variables nécessaires au template !
            'listAdverts' => $listAdverts
        ));
    }

    public function viewAction($id)
    {
        $advert = array(
            'title'   => 'Recherche développpeur Symfony2',
            'id'      => $id,
            'author'  => 'Alexandre',
            'content' => 'Nous recherchons un développeur Symfony2 débutant sur Lyon. Blabla…',
            'date'    => new \Datetime()
        );

        return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:view.html.twig', array(
            'advert' => $advert
        ));
    }
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        // ...

        $advert = array(
            'title'   => 'Recherche développpeur Symfony',
            'id'      => $id,
            'author'  => 'Alexandre',
            'content' => 'Nous recherchons un développeur Symfony débutant sur Lyon. Blabla…',
            'date'    => new \Datetime()
        );

        return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:edit.html.twig', array(
            'advert' => $advert
        ));
    }

    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {

        $advert = new Advert();
        $advert->setTitle('Recherc');
        $advert->setAuthor('Alexandre');
        $advert->setContent("Nous ");

        // On peut ne pas définir ni la date ni la publication,
        // car ces attributs sont définis automatiquement dans le constructeur

        // On récupère l'EntityManager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // Étape 1 : On « persiste » l'entité
        $em->persist($advert);

        // Étape 2 : On « flush » tout ce qui a été persisté avant
        $em->flush();

        // Si la requête est en POST, c'est que le visiteur a soumis le formulaire

        return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:add.html.twig');
    }

}
```

But sadly it doesn't creat the  row in the advert table inside MySQL databse.

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT * FROM advert"   

                          **shows** 
array(0) {
}
```

My table is empty and exist already :

```
mysql> describe advert;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| author    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| published | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from advert
    -> ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_symfony |
+-------------------+
| advert            |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**app\config\config.yml :**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
```

Is there any proposition of solution? thanks!

Comment: would you please translate those French stuff into Englis?

Comment: The use of entity Advert is missing on your file Symfony\src\OC\PlatformBundle\Controller\AdvertController.php. Also did you check log files?

Comment: @MatthewK : yes i forgot use of entity in Advertcontroller , it works now. thanks!